# How to resize Apple partition?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, diskutil, efi

How to resize for Linux?

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            249.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

`diskutil resizePartition dis0s1 100GB`?

Comment: There's about 50 different answers already provided for resizing partitions for Linux.  Have you tried any of those answers?  If so, what errors did you receive?

Comment: I saw a web page which described the CLI approach above to shrink a partition but failed to cite.  I'm sure there are a multitude of answers, but, no, I didn't see anything which, to me, explained how to create free space for another OS.  In all fairness, this might be, or should be, a duplicate question.  But duplicate of which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Disk Utility for macOS Sierra: Partition a physical disk using Disk Utility](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph22240?locale=en_US)

**Please make sure to preform a [backup](https://support.apple.com/mac-backup) prior to partitioning.** Although a standard process, there's always an increased risk of corruption or failure when modifying partitions. *But this shouldn't be an issue as you have been backing up regularly........right?*

> Disk Utility for macOS Sierra: Partition a physical disk using Disk
>
> ### Utility
>
> Partitioning a storage device divides it into individual partitions,
>   which are listed as separate volumes under the Devices section in the
>   Finder sidebar. You may need to partition a disk if you want to
>   install multiple operating systems or if you need to change the
>   device’s format.
>
> If you’re partitioning your internal physical disk because you want to
>   install Windows, use Boot Camp Assistant.
>
> WARNING: To prevent the loss of data on your Fusion Drive, don’t
>   connect it to a Mac that’s using a version of OS X earlier than
>   v10.8.5. For more information, see the Apple Support article Only
>   connect OS X Mavericks Fusion drives to OS X Mountain Lion v10.8.5 or
>   later.
>
> [image]
>
> You can easily create new partitions on a device with at least one
>   volume that contains data, if it has space available.
>
> Important: As a precaution, it’s best to back up your data before
>   creating new partitions on your device.
>
> Add a volume to a device without erasing existing data
>
> 1. Select the device in the sidebar, then click the Partition button [image].
>
> Internal storage devices appear under the Internal section in the
>   sidebar. External devices appear under the External section in the
>   sidebar.
>
> When you select a volume that already has data on it, the pie chart
>   shows a shaded area representing the amount of data on the volume and
>   an unshaded area representing the amount of free space available for
>   another volume. Disk Utility also reports whether the volume can be
>   removed or resized.
>
> If you see a small volume with an asterisk, the partition is smaller
>   than can be represented at the correct scale in the chart.
>
> 2. Click the Add button [image].
>
> Disk Utility splits the volume into two, leaving the data in one
>   volume, and creating a new, empty volume. If the existing volume is
>   less than half-full, Disk Utility creates two volume of equal size.
>   Otherwise, it creates one volume large enough for the existing data,
>   and another volume with the remaining space. Depending on the space
>   available, you can create multiple volumes by selecting the new
>   partition, then clicking the Add button [![enter image description
>   here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRyV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRyV.png).
>
> 3. Click each volume in the pie chart on the left, then enter a name for it.
>
> For MS-DOS (FAT) and ExFAT volumes, the name must be eleven characters
>   or less.
>
> 4. Enter the size or drag the divider to increase or decrease the size of each volume.
> 5. For each volume, click the Format pop-up menu, then choose a format.
>
>    - Mac OS Extended (Journaled): Uses the Mac format (Journaled HFS Plus) to protect the integrity of the hierarchical file system.
>    - Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted): Uses the Mac format, requires a password, and encrypts the partition.
>    - Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled): Uses the Mac format and is case sensitive to file and folder names. For example, folders named
>        “Homework” and “HOMEWORK” are two different folders.
>    - Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled, Encrypted): Uses the Mac format, is case sensitive to folder names, requires a password, and
>        encrypts the volume.
>    - MS-DOS (FAT): Use for Windows volumes that are 32 GB or less.
>    - ExFAT: Use for Windows volumes that are over 32 GB.
> 6. Click Apply.
>
> Click Show Details to view the step-by-step process of creating a new
>   volume.
>
> 7. When Disk Utility is finished creating the volumes, click Done.
>
> After you partition a storage device, an icon for each volume appears
>   in both the Disk Utility sidebar and the Finder sidebar.
>
> Enlarge a volume If you have multiple volumes on a device and one of
>   them is running out of space, you may be able to enlarge it without
>   losing any of the files on it.
>
> To enlarge a volume, you must delete the volume that comes after it on
>   the device, then move the end point of the volume you want to enlarge
>   into the freed space. You can’t enlarge the last volume on a device.
>
> WARNING: When you delete a volume, all data on it is erased. Be sure
>   to back up your data before you begin.
>
> 1. In the sidebar, select the device that contains the volume you want to enlarge, then click the Partition button [![enter image description
>      here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRyV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRyV.png).
> 2. In the pie chart on the left, select the volume you want to remove, then click the Remove button .
> 3. Click Apply.
>
>    The volume is removed, reformatted, and all free space is assigned to
>      the previous volume.
> 4. Click Done.
>
> Erase and repartition a device You can erase all volumes on a device
>   and create new ones. For example, if you want to change the partition
>   map of a USB, Thunderbolt, or other storage device from Master Boot
>   Record to GUID Partition Map. If you simply want to erase a volume,
>   see [Erase a
>   volume](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=dskutl14079&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=El%20Capitan%20Disk%20Utility%20HelpPP512).
>
> WARNING: Erasing and partitioning a device destroys all data on all
>   volumes of the device.
>
> 1. Select the device in the sidebar you want to erase and repartition, then click the [Erase
>      button](https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/Product_Help/en_US/PUBLIC_USERS/PP512/IL_erase_enabled.png).
>
> Note: You can’t erase the device that contains your startup volume.
>
> 2. Enter a name for the initial volume.
> 3. Click the Map pop-up menu, then choose a format for the initial partition.
>
> For MS-DOS and ExFAT partitions, the name must be eleven characters or
>   less.
>
> - GUID Partition Map: Used for all Intel-based Mac computers.
> - Master Boot Record: Used for Windows partitions that will be formatted as MS-DOS (FAT) or ExFAT.
> - Apple Partition Map: Used for compatibility with older PowerPC-based Mac computers.
>
>   4. Click Erase, then click Done.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @fsb There should be a tool to convert the format of Apple Support pages to SE markdown.

Comment: @fsb Better...?

Comment: Looks good, thx.  This way the text will get picked up by people who search.

Comment: @fsb Can I get the.........upvote ;-)

Comment: It does say, but the most important bit was « do a complete backup »...

Comment: @SolarMike Done.

Comment: @JBis well done! - I was not moaning though - just trying to highlight it for the OP... I think many answers on here should start with "do a backup.." Plus 1 from me anyway.

Comment: @SolarMike You are totally correct. I was just....you know...lazy (see edits). But it prevents the future question *HELP I LOST ALL MY DATA BECAUZE I FRGT TO BKUP B 4 PARTITONING*

Comment: I can't seem to get the GUI from within the OS, but only when using `rEFInd`.  Also, when I click the `+` to create a partition when there's free space I just get back a generic "failed" type error.  An error which I've seen others make mention of.  FYI.  (I'm reasonably confident that Lubuntu will detect the free space and install itself accordingly.  Hopefully.)